# Is the quoted range of an RF module based on two identical modules?

Tags: rf

Take for example [this](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1718776.pdf) 433MHz transceiver module. It's quoted range is 300m.

What does this value mean? Is this the distance when the signal strength dies down to 0%?

Does this mean if I were to buy two of these (one for transmit, other for receiving), I would get a theoretical range of ~600m?

Comment: It's meaningless without a description of the antennae that were used. Try asking the supplier.

Comment: I would assume that the advertised range is the maximum distance you can communicate between two identical transceivers under ideal conditions (at UHF, that means line-of-sight).  Under poorer conditions (trees or buildings between units), the range is likely to be less.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things to consider about radio transmissions. One is the power output and how far that can be expected to be reasonably detected and the 2nd is how much bandwidth you are using because this limits the signal that is needed by the receiver.

Starting with the receiver, at a given data rate it can be expected, at ambient temperatures to successfully receive. -154 dBm + 10log (data rate). So, at 1000 bps the anticipated signal strength needed will be -124 dBm. At 1Mbps this increases to -94dBm.

Given perfect conditions a transmission will attenuate at 32.5dB + 20log(MHz) + 20log(kilometres), so at 1GHz and 10km, the output power from the transmit antenna is reduced by 32.5 + 60 + 20 decibels = 112.5 dB reduction and if you were transmitting 1000 bps at 1 watt, you'd probably be ok with minor obstructions and reasonable line of sight.

You should be able to estimate what the real distance of your actual radio modules are now and report back how they stack up against the marketing claims.

Comment: +1 for providing the tools to calculate the answer rather than giving the plain answer. Maybe you could add references for the various figures?

Comment: Isn't the 20log(MHZ) at 1000 bps = -60 dB? and *NOT* the +60 dB you wrote?

Comment: @placeholder the MHz part is the transmission carrier frequency and I used 1GHz in the above. The datarate only applies to the -154 dBm formula for min receive power needed.